# Cannot access empty property error in Advanced Access Manager

Tags: plugins, php, authentication

As explained in the reply of [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-advanced-access-manager-wp-33-fatal-error) by the Advanced Access Manager's author I've changed the current getCurrentUserRole function in the path `/wp-content/plugins/advanced_access_manager/module` with this new code:

```
function getCurrentUserRole() {
    if (is_object($this->data) && isset($this->data->{$this->cap_key})) {
       $result = $this->data->{$this->cap_key};
    } else {
       $result = array();
    }    
    return $result;
}
```

But I get an error when trying to access through `www.foosite.com/wp-admin`. Here is the apache log error message:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property in
>   /var/www/foosite/wp-content/plugins/advanced-access-manager/module/class-module_user.php
>   on line 29

The line error corresponds with the if statement, so I've tried to fix it using `isset`:

```
function getCurrentUserRole() {
    if (isset($this->data) && is_object($this->data) && is_array($this->data->{$this->cap_key})) {
        $result = array_keys($this->data->{$this->cap_key});
    } else {
        $result = array();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Unfortunately the error remains the same.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I've made that it's now working properly:

```
function getCurrentUserRole() {
  if (isset($this->data) && isset($this->data->{$this->cap_key}) && is_object($this->data) && is_array($this->data->{$this->cap_key}) ) {
     $result = array_keys($this->data->{$this->cap_key});
  } else {
     $result = array();
  }

  return $result;
}
```